# Maximum duration of user speech input in seconds for Amazon Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am creating an Amazon Alexa skill and would like to know the maximum duration of user input in seconds that a slot can hold. More specifically the AMAZON.SearchQuery type slot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is an official answer to this anywhere in public docs, but I don't think you'll be able to capture more than a few seconds (~8 max ?) of input. Plus if Alexa detects the user is done speaking, she will stop listening and process the utterance. Even a slight pause could be interpreted as the end of speech input.

I don't know your particular use case, but given all that, I would not recommend that slot type as a reliable way to capture long transcriptions. I don't believe there is a good way for skills to do at all currently.

Answer (score 1):

This Amazon Lex blog is from 2017. I don't know if it will still work, but you can give it a shot.

[Capturing Voice Input in a Browser and sending it to Amazon Lex](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/capturing-voice-input-in-a-browser/)